# Trying to incluide solr server into my java project and starting it

Tags: java, eclipse, solr, server, runnable-jar

I have a java project and i'm trying to include a solr server into my project and start it.

I copy de folders of the server into my eclipse structhure and start the server with Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path/solr.cmd start") but when I create the Runnable jar it doesn't work.

can you help me?

thanks

```
package prueba_solr;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class arrancar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {

        // Arrancar el servidor Apache SOLR
            arrancar();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }

    private static  void arrancar() {
        System.out.println("Arrancando...");

         String comando = "./bin/models/ir/bin/solr.cmd start"; // SI EN ECLIPSE. NO EN EL JAR


        try {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,comando);

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Please, provide [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), else it's unclear what your exact setup is.

Comment: I have included code